# Is there a passive form of "to vanish"?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

I came across the sentence:

> The foundations of democracy are being vanished.

I hadn't seen the verb being used in this way before, is it proper English?

Comment: This is similar to the use of "disappeared" as a transitive verb to describe what happened to journalists and political opponents of authoritarian regimes in Central and South America, which became popular in the '70s.

Comment: I'm familiar with "to be disappeared". I can't find its particular meaning in dictionaries either. Is there a good database that covers these meanings?

Comment: Per @Robusto's comment, to be used in a *passive* construction implies the verb is being used ***transitively***, which is [still?] "non-standard" for verbs like ***vanish, disappear*** (though such usages are definitely gaining traction). I'm not sure whether I'd say the same about, for example, ***I can't just magic it** [your problem] **away***, which has been idiomatically fine for many Brits for a *long* time (but I doubt many competent native speakers would say ***My problem was magicked away***).

Comment: 'The magician put the girl in the box and then vanished her. Just before she was vanished, there was a puff of smoke.' I can't see anything wrong with any of this myself, but it may not be used enough to call it 'idiomatic'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers “was magicked” appears quite commonly in fantasy fiction, e.g., Tamora Pierce’s works; this recent Guardian piece referred to luggage that “was magicked ahead” https://www.theguardian.com/travel/2019/nov/03/walking-holiday-italy-umbria-trail-of-saint-francis-of-assisi

Comment: But why not just use "are vanishing"? I think that this semantically fits what they were trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convey the almost exact meaning (and assuming that *are being disappeared*, and by extension *are being vanished*, is unacceptable), you have to use a helper verb and the infinitive:

> The foundations of democracy are being ***made to*** *vanish*.

---

Any verb other than *vanish* will convey a slightly different meaning, and it will become a game of synonyms.

Here, however, are a few possibilities:

> The foundations of democracy are being *removed*.
>   The foundations of democracy are being *eroded*.
>   The foundations of democracy are being *diminished*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "vanish" in the passive, but it's rare and typically used in stage magic contexts or in other situations where something is made to disappear suddenly and miraculously, rather than the given example.

Merriam-Webster lists [vanish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vanish) as transitive as well as intransitive. The common sense is intransitive as in their example "The missing girl vanished without a trace a year ago."

But according to Merriam-Webster it can also be used to mean "to cause to disappear". This transitive sense can be reversed into the passive, although examples are uncommon. The transitive sense is often used in the world of stage magic, with various tricks promising to "vanish a rabbit" (e.g. [USA Magic Tricks](https://usamagictricks.com/deluxe-take-apart-vanish-timco-magic-p-81276.html)), or "he whisked the cloth away and the rabbit was vanished" ([Magic Cafe forums](https://www.themagiccafe.com/forums/viewtopic.php?topic=22038&forum=7)).

Another non-magic example is a newspaper article discussing a product that can "vanish spots overnight" ([Manchester Evening News](https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/whats-on/whats-on-news/shoppers-praise-26p-stickers-vanish-24744529)).

Hence "vanish" as a transitive verb typically involves a fast disappearance, like magic, so "democracy is being vanished" will have the wrong connotations - democracy made to disappear by a guy in a top hat and cloak. But in other contexts something like "a rabbit was vanished by the magician" or "her spots were vanished by the medicine" would be grammatical, although arguably awkward.

Comment: For transitive *vanish* [the OED gives  “To cause to disappear; to remove from sight. **Now chiefly with reference to conjuring.”**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/221604)  I wonder whether R-dropping speakers lacking the normal *TRAP–BATH* split ever end up having a weird *vanish–varnish* merger, thus leading to a request like “Dear, please make sure to varnish that old chair while I’m away this weekend” that sees the chair thrown away altogether rather than refurbished. :)